# Apagar pergunta com recompensa antes de terminar o tempo

Tags: suporte, recompensa, exclusão

Posso excluir uma pergunta com recompensa, mesmo antes de dar o tempo da recompensa ?

Comment: Acho que a resposta é "Não". Não tem como nem fechar uma pergunta com recompensa.